# About compiling Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, compilation

My question is two fold:

1. Firefox browser

I compiled firefox source-code in releases : 
https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.0/source/

but after I finish compiling, I met Nightly, not Firefox browser.

I would execute Firefox.

Might be there is any option to build Firefox?
( I searched the build configuration, but cannot find the option about browser)

If anyone have an experience about compiling Firefox from its source code, please help :)

2. Rust dependency
   When I compiled Firefox, I encountered error below:

   0:06.97    Compiling mp4parse_capi v0.6.0 (file:///home/signal/Desktop/firefox_source/firefox-53.0/media/libstagefright/binding/mp4parse_capi)
   0:06.97      Running `/home/signal/.cargo/bin/rustc --crate-name build_script_build /home/signal/Desktop/firefox_source/firefox-53.0/media/libstagefright/binding/mp4parse_capi/build.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=2 -C codegen-units=1 -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=2476a8a7a86fe109 -C extra-filename=-2476a8a7a86fe109 --out-dir /home/signal/Desktop/firefox_source/firefox-53.0/obj-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/toolkit/library/gtest/rust/./release/build/mp4parse_capi-2476a8a7a86fe109 -L dependency=/home/signal/Desktop/firefox_source/firefox-53.0/obj-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/toolkit/library/gtest/rust/./release/deps`
   0:07.05 error[E0463]: can't find crate for `cheddar`
   0:07.05  --> /home/signal/Desktop/firefox_source/firefox-53.0/media/libstagefright/binding/mp4parse_capi/build.rs:1:1
   0:07.05   |
   0:07.05 1 | extern crate cheddar;
   0:07.05   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
   0:07.05
   0:07.05 error: aborting due to previous error
   0:07.05
   0:07.06 error: Could not compile `mp4parse_capi`.
   0:07.06
   0:07.06 Caused by:
   0:07.06   process didn't exit successfully: `/home/signal/.cargo/bin/rustc --crate-name build_script_build /home/signal/Desktop/firefox_source/firefox-53.0/media/libstagefright/binding/mp4parse_capi/build.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=2 -C codegen-units=1 -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=2476a8a7a86fe109 -C extra-filename=-2476a8a7a86fe109 --out-dir /home/signal/Desktop/firefox_source/firefox-53.0/obj-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/toolkit/library/gtest/rust/./release/build/mp4parse_capi-2476a8a7a86fe109 -L dependency=/home/signal/Desktop/firefox_source/firefox-53.0/obj-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/toolkit/library/gtest/rust/./release/deps` (exit code: 101)
   0:07.06 Build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
   0:08.68 error: build failed
   0:08.68 /home/signal/Desktop/firefox_source/firefox-53.0/config/rules.mk:966: recipe for target 'force-cargo-library-build' failed
   0:08.68 make[5]: *** [force-cargo-library-build] Error 101
   0:08.68 /home/signal/Desktop/firefox_source/firefox-53.0/config/recurse.mk:71: recipe for target 'toolkit/library/gtest/rust/target' failed

That seems I need a rust package to resolve dependecny.
But in the latest version, I could complie firefox without any error.

Could anyone give any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
build = false
```

to media/libstagefright/binding/mp4parse_capi/Cargo.toml fixed the issue.
More info here: [don't try to build mp4parse](https://reviewboard.mozilla.org/r/111682/diff/1#index_header)